# Variable not recognized in else statement in a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scope, expansion

I have the follow code:

```
ECHO OFF
:LOOP
set c=
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
tasklist | find /i "calc.exe" >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
  ECHO easymeetingOnCall is running
  taskkill /IM calc.exe /F
  set c=true
  Timeout /T 10
  goto LOOP
) ELSE (
  IF "!c!" == "true" (
    ECHO l'applicazione easymeetingOnCall è spenta.
    Timeout /T 10
    goto exitLoop
  )
  ECHO easymeetingOnCall is not running
  Timeout /T 5 /Nobreak
  GOTO LOOP
)
:exitLoop
```

My problem is that the follow condition

```
IF "!c!" == "true"
```

Into the else statement, is not recognized.
If I write `echo !c!` It doesn't output any result.
I `set enabledelayedexpansion` before, so I don't know why of this behavior.

Could you help me?
Thanks to all.

Comment: You goto :loop which `set`s c to nothing. Move `set c=` to above `:loop`

Comment: How do you expect `c` having a value, when you explicitly `set c=` first thing after `:loop`?

Comment: My recommendations: Replace `tasklist | find /i "calc.exe" >nul 2>&1` by `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq calc.exe" /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "calc.exe" >nul`, replace `IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0` by `if not errorlevel 1` and if possible terminate the real application by using `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM calc.exe` without option `/F` if the real application terminates gracefully on receiving the `WM_CLOSE` message instead of killing the application brutally by operating system. Option `/F` should be used only if the application does not terminate itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at the following extraction from your code.

```
ECHO OFF
:LOOP
set c=
....
set c=true
goto :LOOP
```

You are explicitly telling the if statement to `goto :loop` where directly after you `set c=` which now gives it no value. Move the `set c=` to above to label to retain the value you've set.

I however suggest a few changes. you can get away without `delayedexpansion` and do actually require all the for loops. Using `taskkill` to explicitly search for the app is better than listing all, also already mentioned to you in a comment by @Mofi. Lastly, it is not really good practice to set single character variables, though it does not always cause issues, I would suggest using multple character variable names. I just changed your variable `%c%` to `%_c%`

```
@echo off & set _c=
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Calc.exe" | find /i "Calc"
goto :_%errorlevel%
:_0
  ECHO easymeetingOnCall is running
  taskkill /IM calc.exe /F
  set _c=true
  Timeout /T 10
  goto loop
:_1
  IF "%_c%" == "true" (
    ECHO l'applicazione easymeetingOnCall è spenta.
    Timeout /T 10
    goto exitloop
  )
  ECHO easymeetingOnCall is not running
  Timeout /T 5 /Nobreak
  goto loop
  :exitloop
```

**Edit**, as you wanted to do this with a list:

```
@echo off & set _c=
set "list=calc.exe StickyNot.exe wordpad.exe"
for %%a in (%list%) do call :loop %%a
goto :eof
:loop
set task=%1
 tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1" | find /i "%1"
   if not errorlevel 1 (
   ECHO easymeetingOnCall is running %1
   taskkill /IM %1 /F
   set _c=true
   Timeout /T 10
)
if "%_c%" == "true" (
    ECHO l'applicazione easymeetingOnCall è spenta. %1
    Timeout /T 10
    goto exitloop
  )
    echo easymeetingOnCall is not running %1
    Timeout /T 5 /Nobreak
    goto :loop
  :exitloop
```

Be aware, if the first process is not running, it will loop forever until it is found, then only kill it and go to the next process. If you do not want that, then change `goto :loop` in the last line to exit loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i tried and it works. 
I want to wait for every process until it is found, and only after it is found kill it.
And is what the script do. Thanks so much !